# XHR POST 404 error when using fetch api with NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, express, fetch-api

I am currently learning how to use the fetch api for my front-end. I continue to get the XHR 404 POST error.

```
    //Backend file
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv");

const Port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
);

const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const Mail = require("nodemailer/lib/mailer");
require("nodemailer-mailgun-transport");
app.use(express.json());
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("/public");
  res.sendFile("/public/js/mail.js");
});
app.listen(Port, (req, res) => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${Port}`);
});

app.post("/email"),
  (req, res) => {
    FromMailjs = req.body;
    console.log(FromMailjs);
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      auth: {
        user: process.env.Email,
        pass: process.env.Pass,
      },
    });

    const MailOptions = {
      from: req.body.Email,
      to: process.env.MyEmail,
      text: `${req.body.FirstName}, ${req.body.LastName}
        , ${req.body.PhoneNumber}, ${req.body.Email}`,
    };
    transporter.sendMail(MailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.send("error");
      } else {
        console.log("Email sent");
        res.send("success");
      }
    });
  };

//Frontend file
const ContactForm = document.querySelector(".contact-form");

ContactForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let FirstName = document.getElementById("Fname");
  let LastName = document.getElementById("Lname");
  let PhoneNumber = document.getElementById("PhoneNumber");
  let Email = document.getElementById("Email");

  const FormData = {
    FirstName: FirstName.value,
    LastName: LastName.value,
    PhoneNumber: PhoneNumber.value,
    Email: Email.value,
  };
  const PostOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(FormData),
  };
  console.log(FormData);
  fetch("/email", PostOptions);
});
```

XHRPOSThttp://localhost:5000/email
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 27ms]

I have tried changing the routes hoping that it was just a routing issue and I still get the same error. I was using XHR before fetch and I got the same 404 error. My front-end is receiving the correct information but I can't get my backend to receive the information.

Comment: 1. Share code, not screenshots of code. 2. If you get an error share the error message. Press the edit button to make changes. don't reply to my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Please use:

```
app.post("/email", (req, res) => {
```

Instead of:

```
app.post("/email"),
  (req, res) => {
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked! Thank you so much.